# How to draw a seismic cube from ocean

Tags: ocean, petrel

Can I programmatically merge two seismic cubes in petrel?

I have been trying to achieve this by redrawing a seismic cube whose parameters would be the summation of the two seismic cubes I want to merge. But I cant even draw a seismic cube from my ocean program, please is there a way I can do this?

Comment: If your seismic cubes have different sizes, orientation, geometry, amplitude values and sampling rates and you want to ignore dead traces, you may consider trying the [Survey Merge](http://www.ocean.slb.com/Pages/Product.aspx?category=allpetrel(Base)&cat=Petrel&pid=PSVM-B1(Base)) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to merge the values, I think you could simply create a new seismic cube, do some arithmetic operation you need to do, and write the values to the new cube. Assuming you already understand about create a cube from template Maybe something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cubeResult.NumSamplesIJK.I; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cubeResult.NumSamplesIJK.J; j++)
    {
        ITrace trace = cubeResult.GetTrace(i, j);
        ITrace trace1 = cube1.GetTrace(i, j);
        ITrace trace2 = cube2.GetTrace(i, j);
        for (int k = 0; k < cube1.NumSamplesIJK.K; k++)
        {
           // do arithmetic operation yo need
        }                          
      }

 }
```